# Play audio file on repeat while fading volume up from 0% to 100% in 2 hours

Tags: linux, bash, audio, terminal, playback

I've tried `play alarm.flac fade 7200 repeat 999` but the volume-fade resets itself to 0% on every repeat, it should just rise continuously and then indefinitely settle on 100% as the audio repeats forever.

**Requirements**

- Doesn't use system wide volume control
- CLI / Linux

Comment: Can you write a bash script to call `play alarm.flac fade 7200` and just loop while true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command

> ```
> play alarm.flac fade 7200 repeat 999
> ```

applies `fade` to the input and `repeat`s the (short) result. You want to `repeat` the input and apply `fade` to the (long) result. The order of effect matters. Run this:

```
play alarm.flac repeat 999 fade 7200
```

Note to "repeat forever" you need `repeat -`. You may also prefer `fade t 7200`.

Answer (score 0):

```
play alarm.flac fade 7200; play alarm.flac repeat 999
```

~OR~

Make a script file as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

play ~/test.flac fade 7200
while(true)
  play ~/test.flac
```

Run said script file.